# I have use correct table but show the error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using Sarav **Multiple Authentication in Laravel 5.1**. User login and registration has been fine.
But when I click on forget password link and submit that form show

```
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '' (SQL: delete from `` where `email` = pawandongol@gmail.com)
```

I can not be succeeded to send the password reset link through reset form.

Please help be to solve out this error.
Thank you!!!

Comment: If you look at the error message, no table name is being provided. Can you provide the model for the table?

Comment: In laravel It has default PasswordController which are used for password reset funtionality in case of forget password through sending reset link.

Comment: But have you got a table for it to use or modified the default settings for it to use. I have checked out the package and the subsequent blog and there are no steps in there that should stop it from working. Do you have a  password resets table?

Comment: Yes, I have password_resets table

Answer (score 0):

I belive you already have the solution, but, for others:

"
Got same error and fixed it by changing one line in migration file what was created before.
My file:
/database/migrations/2016_02_29_160852_entrust_setup_tables.php

$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('')
to
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
"

Source: [enter link description here](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/510)
and [enter link description here](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/567)